# Some data lost when decode JSON to PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I can decode JSON in PHP To array But some data that have in JSON disappear when decode to array.

This is my JSON file

```
[
  {
    "name": "Games1",
    "price": "€ 25.53",
    "platform": "<span class=\"platform battle-net\"></span>",
    "region": "GLOBAL",
    "url": "localhost"
  },
  {
    "name": "Games2",
    "price": "€ 24.99",
    "platform": "<span class=\"platform xbox-live\"></span>",
    "region": "GLOBAL",
    "url": "localhost"
  }
]
```

This is my php code

```
$data = file_get_contents("game.json");
for ($i = 0; $i <= 31; ++$i) { 
    $data = str_replace(chr($i), "", $data); 
}

$data = str_replace(chr(127), "", $data);
if (0 === strpos(bin2hex($data), 'efbbbf')) {
   $data = substr($data, 3);
}

$data = json_decode($data,true);
print_r($data);
```

My result from print_r($data);

```
    Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Games1 [price] => € 25.53 [platform] => [region] => GLOBAL [url] => localhost ) 
[1] => Array ( [name] => Games2 [price] => € 24.99 [platform] => [region] => GLOBAL [url] => localhost ) )
```

My value in Platform is disappear. Can anyone know What is the problem?

Comment: Can you give output of var_dump($data)?

Comment: If your using a browser to view the output, then do a view source, the output is most likely there but your browser is interpreting the HTML tags.

Comment: Why do you need all that `str_replace()` stuff? Why would you have extraneous characters in `game.json`?

Answer (score 4):

Your JSON contains HTML tags, and these are being interpreted by the browser when it shows the result of `print_r()`. Use the browser's View Source command to see the raw output and you should see the spans.

You can also use `htmlentities()` to convert them to escaped characters, which will be shown as is by the browser.

```
$output = print_r($data, true);
echo "<pre>" . htmlentities($output, ENT_COMPAT) . "</pre>";
```

Using `<pre>` will maintain the formatting as well.

Answer (score -1):

In order to keep HTML inside of JSON, you have to follow multiple rules:

1. Escape quotation marks
           `<span class=\"class-name\"><\/span>`
2. Escape the forward slash in closing tags `<\/span>`
3. In self closing tags, leave a space between slash and closing bracket.
           `<img ... />`
4. Make sure to encode special character entities like this: 
           `&euro;`

Additionally, you can avoid duplicating your 
`<span>` tags, and just store their class name like this: `"platform": "battle-net",` or `"platform": "xbox-live",`.